# tikz: mathematical expressions in variable names without pgf macros

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following diagram:

[image]

I would like to be able to evaluate mathematical expressions in variable names.  For example I would like to be able to write `(a$\i+1$\j)` in this code to generate the above output:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=to]
  \node (a) at (0,0) {};
  \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3}
     \foreach \j in {0,1,2}
        \node (a\i\j) at ($(a) + (\i, -\j)$) {};

  \foreach \i in {0,1,2}
     \foreach \j in {0,1,2}
        \draw[->] (a\i\j) -- (a$\i+1$\j);

  \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3}
     \foreach \j in {0,1}
        \draw[->,dotted] (a\i\j) -- (a\i$\j+1$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to make this work without using pgf macros like pgfmathsetmacro and pgfmathtruncatemacro, which feel a bit hacky?  And, separately, is there a better way to generate the diagram?

Comment: Quick shot: `(a\the\numexpr\i+1\relax\j)`. Well, for playing around it would certainly help if you provide a complete and compilable minimal working example (MWE).

Comment: Thanks.  That's closer to what I was looking for.  I've edited my question to be more like a MWE though it doesn't compile of course but replacing `(a$\i+1$\j)` etc. with your suggestion should compile.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `count` function of the `foreach`-loop. In combination with `ifnum` this is pretty powerful and does the magic. This way you can also put all your code into one loop and save some compilation time.

See the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x [count=\xx from -1] in {0,...,3} {
   \foreach \y [count=\yy from -1] in {0,...,3} {
    \node (a\x\y) at (\x,-\y) {};
    \ifnum\xx>-1
     \draw [->] (a\xx\y) -- (a\x\y);
    \fi        
    \ifnum\yy>-1
     \draw [->, dotted] (a\x\yy) -- (a\x\y);
    \fi
   }
  }  
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered image]

Answer (score 3):

You could try to use the `evaluate` opton of the `\foreach`, but I prefer a simper approach using `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` to perform the arithmetic computation:

[image]

### Code: `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=to]
  \node (a) at (0,0) {};
  \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3}
     \foreach \j in {0,1,2}
        \node (a\i\j) at ($(a) + (\i, -\j)$) {};

  \foreach \i in {0,1,2}
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\IncrementI}{\i+1}%
     \foreach  \j in {0,1,2}
        \draw[->] (a\i\j) -- (a\IncrementI\j);

  \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3}
     \foreach \j in {0,1}
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\IncrementJ}{\j+1}%
        \draw[->,dotted] (a\i\j) -- (a\i\IncrementJ);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Code: `evaluate`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=to]
  \node (a) at (0,0) {};
  \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3}
     \foreach \j in {0,1,2}
        \node (a\i\j) at ($(a) + (\i, -\j)$) {};

  \foreach [evaluate={\IncrementI=int(\i+1)}] \i in {0,1,2}
     \foreach  \j in {0,1,2}
        \draw[->] (a\i\j) -- (a\IncrementI\j);

  \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3}
     \foreach [evaluate={\IncrementJ=int(\j+1)}] \j in {0,1}
        \draw[->,dotted] (a\i\j) -- (a\i\IncrementJ);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the exact syntax of `\foreach`? I mean, one is `\foreach \x in {1,2,3}{do something with \x}` but how does this one works? It grabs until the next `;` or what?

Comment: @Manuel: It grabs the next value when it is comma separated, but if you use `\foreach \x in {1,3,...,9}` it will translate that to being the same as `\foreach \x in {1,3,5,7,9}`.  There are may other options as well, but I think that that should be a separate question (if it is not clear from the tikz-pgf manual).

Comment: @Manuel If it doesn't have a brace pair, it grabs until the next `;` otherwise it executes the whole scope at each spin.

Comment: @percusse That's what I thought, but I didn't know for sure. Peter, that's it, if you think I should remove the comment I will remove it, if not, I will leave it here :)

Answer (score 1):

We could hack the coordinate parser so that the OP's desired syntax was possible. This would only work for named coordinates which do not start with `$` if the `calc` library is loaded, and unlikely to work at all if category code of `$` is changed (e.g., made active):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\let\tikz@@parse@node=\tikz@parse@node    
\def\tikz@parse@node#1(#2){%
  \pgfutil@in@{$}{#2}%$
  \ifpgfutil@in@%
    \let\tikz@next=\tikz@parse@node@calc%
  \else%
    \let\tikz@next=\tikz@@parse@node%
  \fi%
  \tikz@next{#1}(#2)%    
}    
\def\tikz@parse@node@calc#1(#2$#3$#4){%
  \pgfmathparse{\tikzcoordinatefunction{#3}}%
  \edef\tikz@tmp{#2\pgfmathresult#4}%
  \def\tikz@marshal{\tikz@parse@node{#1}}%
  \expandafter\tikz@marshal\expandafter(\tikz@tmp)%
}    
\def\tikzcoordinatefunction#1{int(#1)}    
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \foreach \i in {1,...,4}
   \foreach \j in {1,...,4}
     \node (a\i\j) at (\j, -\i) {};    
\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
  \foreach \j in {1,...,3}
    \draw [->] (a\i\j) -- (a\i$\j+1$);    
\foreach \i in {1,...,3}
  \foreach \j in {1,...,4}
    \draw [->, dotted] (a\i\j) -- (a$\i+1$\j);
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]