# tikztimingtable: math in foreach

Tags: foreach, tikz-timing

I have following code:

```tex
\begin{tikztimingtable}[%
  timing/dslope=0.1,
  timing/.style={x=5ex,y=2ex},
  x=5ex,
  timing/rowdist=3ex,
  timing/name/.style={font=\sffamily\scriptsize}
]
    CLK                   & h 10{c} \\
    \begin{extracode}
        \begin{background}
         \vertlines[lightgray,dotted]{}
         \draw [->,>=latex] (0,\rowdist) -- (\twidth,\rowdist);
         \foreach \n in {0,1,...,\twidth}
           \draw (\n+.5,\rowdist+.2) -- +(0,+.0)
               node [above,inner sep=2pt] {\scalebox{1}{\tiny\n}};
        \end{background}
       \end{extracode}
\end{tikztimingtable}
```

Which produces:
[image]

My question is how to get rid of last "5"? I tried to use `\twidth-1` but it gives me an error.

Comment: the pff truncate macro is your friend in such case --

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207344/197451

Comment: How exactly it will help me? I need the foreach to execute one time less.

Comment: suggest elaborate your code so that it can be compiled as standalone example

Comment: Please, always post complete code starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but a demonstration of the truncate macro use -- as the OP was finding it difficult to use `\twidth-1` -- you can now use

```
      \foreach \n in {0,1,...,\twidth}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\j}{\twidth - 1}% added here
       \draw (\n+.5,\rowdist+.2) -- +(0,+.0)
           node [above,inner sep=2pt] {\scalebox{1}{\tiny\n}};
```

You need to give us a compilable code to work with

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (N1) {N1};
\foreach \i in {2,3,..,5}{
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\j}{\i - 1}
  % balance of foreach code
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

EDIT

An alternative to the `\pgfmathtruncate` macro could be the expression

```
  \foreach \n in {1,2,...,\the\numexpr\textwidth-1}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (N1) {N1};
        \foreach \i in {2,3,...,\the\numexpr\i-1}{
           %\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\j}{\i - 1}
            % whatever
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `evaluate` and `using` as in the following code:

```
     \foreach [var=\n, evaluate=\n as \m using int(\n-1)] in {1,...,\twidth}
       \draw (\m+.5,\rowdist+.2) -- +(0,+.0)
           node [above,inner sep=2pt] {\scalebox{1}{\tiny\m}};
```

[image]